# open and write text in c

Tags: c, arrays, io

I have an exercise in c which it asks to get tow parameters (filename, number e.g. k>0).
After, it will create a new file that will get the letter in position k, 2*k , 3*k etc. and will write it in the new file.
It will also create another file that will write the line like the above. e.g. line k , line2*k etc.

My first touch was this but i don't know about make that pointer * the number(k) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * file;
    char c;
    int k;

    printf("Give a number :\n");
    scanf("%d" , k);

    file = fopen("file.txt","r");
    if (file == NULL) 
        printf("File doesn't exist\n");
    else 
    {
        do
        {
        c = getc(file);
        putchar(c);
        }
        while (c != EOF);
    }


    fclose(file);
 return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a question beyond "Please do my homework assignment for me?"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: So what stops you from starting to code ?

Comment: @user7206161 please update your question and don't post tons of code in a comment.

Comment: sorry for that im just new i will update it now

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues:

---

Change `scanf("%d" , k);`to `scanf("%d" , &k);`

---

Change `char c;` to `int c;` because `getc` and `putchar` use `int`.

---

This is wrong:

```
do
{
  c = getc(file);
  putchar(c);
}
while (c != EOF);
```

if `c` is `EOF`, then you shouln't call `putcar`.

---

You check `(file == NULL)`, but then you shouln't call `fclose`. Call `fclose` only if `fopen` has been successful.